# Google Map Fragment not saving state/won't add markers to map onResume

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am fairly new at Android dev, so bear with me. I am having some problems with instance state saving for my google maps api implementation i believe. I am using Android Studio. I am implementing AppCompactActivity to setup a tab view. I am changing fragments in my pager view using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. My problem is that My google maps api will not save state in very certain circumstances. If i am clicking a tab that is >1 index away from my MapFragment index, the state of the map fragment will not be retained and i cannot add markers or a Go Home button to the map, but the map is present.

My initial marker and home location button works, it just won't show back up/allow me to add more markers after i switch to my last tab and switch back to the map tab.

As i said, i am new at android dev, so any advice is appreciative.

This is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Map"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

with main activity xml as this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my PagerAdapter class

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new TabFragment1();
            case 1:
                return new MapViewFragment();
            case 2:
                return new TabFragment2();
            case 3:
                return new TabFragment3();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

this is my MapFragment class

```
public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private static View view;
    /**
     * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not
     * available.
     */

    private static GoogleMap mMap;
    private static Double latitude, longitude;
    private static String quickFilterText="";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);

        // Passing harcoded values for latitude & longitude. Please change as per your need. This is just used to drop a Marker on the Map
        latitude = 26.78;
        longitude = 72.56;

        ImageButton arrowButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.arrowButton);
        arrowButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View newView) {
                RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.filterDropDown);
                EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quickFilter);
                try
                {
                    quickFilterText = text.getText().toString();
                }
                catch(Exception err)
                {

                }
                if(relLayout.getHeight()>0)
                {
                    relLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(relLayout.getWidth(),0));
                }
                else
                {
                    relLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(relLayout.getWidth(),180));
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    /***** Sets up the map if it is possible to do so *****/
    public void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null)
                setUpMap();
        }
    }
    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the
     * camera.
     * <p>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap}
     * is not null.
     */
    private static void setUpMap() {
        // For showing a move to my loction button
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My Home").snippet("Home Address"));
        // For zooming automatically to the Dropped PIN Location
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,
                longitude), 12.0f));
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(map)).getMap(); // getMap is deprecated
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null)
                setUpMap();
        }
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    /**** The mapfragment's id must be removed from the FragmentManager
     **** or else if the same it is passed on the next time then
     **** app will crash ****/

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
}
```

and this is my activity_maps.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/filterDropDown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:weightSum="1">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="Filter"
                    android:id="@+id/filterTextBox"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/quickFilter"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/filterTextBox" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filterDropDown">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Filter"
            android:id="@+id/arrowButton"
            android:background="@drawable/down_arrow"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my other 3 tabs are just simple fragments with a text view inside of them

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    }
}
```

with layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Tab 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the view pager keeps the current fragment, and one fragment to the left and right of it alive. In your pager adapter you are telling it the create a brand new fragment, instead of using the existing one.

```
List<Fragment> myPages; // populate this in the constructor
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return myPages.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myPages.size();
}
```

You should also increase the off screen page limit if you know you will only ever have those four fragments.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

If you run into more problems with the map after doing these two things you may want to set the map fragment to retain its instance state. Override the fragments `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

Comment: ahhh! ok. I couldn't find anything references on state saving 1 index away. I used my tab skeleton code from someone else, so i assumed it was inherent, but i had no idea if my 4th fragment was not retaining state because of an error on my inherent saving, or if i wasn't saving at all. Thanks! I'll try your solution here in a bit and let you know if i have any problems.

Comment: Sorry I'm just now getting back to this. Your answer worked! thank you very much.